# How can I change live status of a table after changes in database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a transactions table having entries performing separate tasks in other tables of database on button click.

What I need to do is, after completion of each task the corresponding row should turn green and those which do not complete will turn red (using bootstrap) one by one without page refresh.

Before Validate button click
[image: Before Validate button click]

After click and page refresh
[image: After click and page refresh]

Here is my displayed table code:

```
<?php
    $sth01 = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM le_planning.transactions");
    $sth01->execute();
    $result01 = $sth01->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count01 = $sth01->rowCount();
    if ($count01 > 0) {
        echo "<div class='container'>
            <table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed' id='tab1' name='tab1' style='width:80%' align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sl. no.</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Proposed date</th>
                </tr>";
                foreach ($result01 as $k) {
                    if ($k['status'] == 0) {
                        ?>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td><?php echo $k['Transaction_ID']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k['Type']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k['Datetime']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    } else if ($k['status'] == 1) {
                        ?>
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td><?php echo $k['Transaction_ID']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k['Type']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k['Datetime']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    } else if ($k['status'] == 2) {
                        ?>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td><?php echo $k['Transaction_ID']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k['Type']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k['Datetime']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            echo "</table>
        </div>";
    } else
        echo "";


if (!empty($_POST['validate_sub']))
{ 
$sth1 = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM le_planning.transactions ORDER BY Datetime ASC");
$sth1->execute();
$result1 = $sth1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//print_r($result1);
$count1 = $sth1->rowCount();
if($count1 > 0)
{
    foreach($result1 as $item)
    {
        $Trans_ID = $item['Transaction_ID'];
        $Type = $item['Type'];
        $Type_ID = $item['Type_ID'];
        $Datetime = $item['Datetime'];

        if($Type=='Production')
        {
           // some code
            }
            if($count2==($a+$b))
            {               // turn green   
                $q5 = "UPDATE le_planning.transactions SET status=1 WHERE Transaction_ID=$Trans_ID";
                $sth5 = $dbo->prepare($q5);
                if($sth5->execute())
                    echo "";
                else
                    echo "Error!";
            }
            else
            {       // turn red
                $q6 = "UPDATE le_planning.transactions SET status=2 WHERE Transaction_ID=$Trans_ID";
                $sth6 = $dbo->prepare($q6);
                if($sth6->execute())
                    echo "";
                else
                    echo "Error!";  
            }   
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
    <form role="form" method="post" name="f1" id="f1" action="<?php echo $SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>">
    <center><input type="submit" value="Validate" class="btn btn-success" id="validate_sub" name="validate_sub"></center>
    </form>
```

By now I have understood that to make each transaction change its color instantly or one could say live updation while all transactions take their time to perform without page refresh, I must use jquery and ajax but I am unable to weave a logic for this one.

PS - I am new to jQuery & AJAX.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You've not given us enough information to help you. It sounds like AJAX is exactly what you need, but we can't tell you what you should call as that's entirely dependent on your own system. Have a read of the jQuery AJAX docs to get an understanding of how AJAX works: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan here is the code as well

Answer (score 0):

check this link . your related problem solution you find from here .

http://www.jqueryajaxphp.com/live-table-edit-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-twitter-bootstrap/

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Comment: I have been through all these posts but they are not what i need here.. 
i simply want to change the color of each row which has successfully executed or not in run time i.e. live status of each row one by one while other rows are under execution after i click on the Validate button.

thanks though :)